# Java Atomicity & a good Compare and Swap framework?

Tags: java, bytecode, atomic

Do you guys think this is a good generic framework for atomic operations?
Also do you think its correct to say With respect to Java applicatitions individual byte codes are atomic as there is no way of executing more than one byte code at a time with a single JVM? So if there was a single byte code for if else, then this if else instruction would be atomic?

```
// CAS, Compare and Swap
public abstract class CASOperation<T> {

protected T valueAtStart;

public CASOperation(){
    valueAtStart = objectToReview();
}

public void exec(){
    synchronized(this){
        while(!valueAtStartEqualsTheCurrent()){
            valueAtStart = objectToReview();
        }
        execImp();
    }
}

private boolean valueAtStartEqualsTheCurrent() {
    if (objectToReview().equals(valueAtStart)){
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

abstract protected T objectToReview();

abstract protected void execImp();
```

---

Its meant to be a compare and execute framework really, so after checking that the original snapped value hasn't changed then we execute some block of code.

Answer (score 8):

I would just use [`java.util.concurrent.AtomicReference`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) unless you *really* need the full equality check instead of a simple `==`.

[`compareAndSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html#compareAndSet%28V,%20V%29) returns a value saying whether or not the value was the expected one, so you can then conditionally execute other code.

Executing the abstract method in a synchronized block sounds like a potentially risky business - there's no indication or constraint of how long that could take.

Put it this way: I think that unless I knew of a *specific* requirement to use something like your proposed framework, I'd stick with the types in `java.util.concurrent.atomic`.

Comment: Yes I was thinking it would be nice to have a generic way for comparing any object hence the need for equals, I'll take a look, cheers.

Comment: @user1037729: You can always loop, performing a `get`, then checking with equality, then doing a `compareAndSet` to check if the value *is* equal, using the existing reference.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you guys think this is a good generic framework for atomic operations?

Yes, it's in the [java.util.concurrent.atomic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html) package.

> if there was a single byte code for "if else", then this "if else" instruction would be atomic?

Not necessarily - one bytecode instruction might translate into more than one machine instruction.

Note: your code uses a synchronized block which is never released within one call - so if the condition is false when entering the block, it might never become true.

Comment: Yep I understand that one byte code is likely to translate into more than one machine instruction but with respect to a single java process  I'd imaging only one byte code could be executed at a time, and therefore would be atomic, surely know other applications could tamper with the memory in a Java process?

Comment: if !valueAtStartEqualsTheCurrent() evaluates to false, that would mean the start value and current are equal and therefore we should exec the  operation.

Comment: if !valueAtStartEqualsTheCurrent() evaluates to true, that would mean the start value and current are not equal and therefore we should not exec the operation. which is what we want, if it never becomes false, thats good as we want the operation to be atomic, or have a missed something?

Comment: @user1037729 You are mixing things. A single java process can execute more than one byte code at a time if there is more than one processor. But even on one processor, 2 threads can be interleaved randomly if you don't use synchronization. For example, a simple expression like `SomeType s = new SomeType();` is not atomic. So an observing thread could see s in the middle of being constructed for example.