# Swap 2 values in 2 different AtomicReferences

Tags: java, concurrency

I tried to implement a swap method for 2 AtomicReferences.

```
public void swap(AtomicReference<Object> a, AtomicReference<Object> b) {
    while (true) {
        Object value1 = a.get();
        Object value2 = b.get();

        if (a.compareAndSet(value1, value2) && b.compareAndSet(value2, value1)) return;
    }
}
```

In my opinion, this solution is not correct. If multiple threads use this method at the same time, it could lead to the following scenario:

```
T1: ...get(); get(); compareAndSet() == true //-> BREAK (scheduler)
T2: ...get(); get(); compareAndSet() == true; compareAndSet() == true; return;
```

This would mean, T1 had set the value of `a` but will fail by setting the value of b. T1 would repeat the process EVEN if AtomicReference a has been set.

Does someone of you have a better idea, how to implement something like this? It would be easy, if you would just have one AtomicReference. Maybe it isn't possible using 2 AtomicReference's and I should consider using one AtomicReference that points to an Object[].

In Scala, this method is super easy to implement, since you have atomic blocks.

```
class Swappy[A](_a: A, _b: A) {

  @volatile
  var a = Ref(_a)
  @volatile
  var b = Ref(_b)

  def swap(): Unit = {
    atomic {
      implicit tx =>
            val tmp = a
            a = b
            b = tmp
    }
  }

  def elems: (A, A) = (a.single(), b.single())
}
```

Comment: Don't know Scala, but I frankly don't see how it can work in principle, unless Scala wraps low-level CPU atomic commands into its own stuff.

Comment: Actually it isn't "real" low-level atomic stuff. But it checks for itself at the end of the block, if everything still is correct (no affected values changed). If not, it will roll back and start from the beginning of the atomic block. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java Atomicity & a good Compare and Swap framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771174/java-atomicity-a-good-compare-and-swap-framework)

Answer (score 1):

I created a solution with a different approach. This should be 100% thread safe. I switched to using just one AtomicReference. If anyone could find a better way, feel free to write an answer. :)

```
package test;

import java.util.concurrent.atomic.*;

public class ScalaSTMPendant {

    AtomicReference<Object[]> a;

    public ScalaSTMPendant(Object a, Object b) {
        this.a = new AtomicReference<>(new Object[] {a,b});
    }

    public void swap() {
        while (true) {
            Object[] origin = a.get();

            Object[] swapped = new Object[] {origin[1], origin[0]};

            if (a.compareAndSet(origin, swapped)) return;
        }
    }

    public Object[] elems() {
        Object[] temp = a.get();
        return new Object[] {temp[0], temp[1]};
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, don't call `a.get()` three times. You can just extract `value1` and `value2` from `origin`.

Answer (score 0):

Would an [Exchanger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) help? I'm not sure who is swapping what, but an Exchanger would help you do a swap atomically.

Also, the scala sample above uses ScalaSTM. You could do the same in Java using another STM implementation (or even ScalaSTM). For example: [Multiverse](http://multiverse.codehaus.org/overview.html).